# How to calculate the sum of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{4^{n-1}}{5^{n-1}}+\frac{4}{5^{n-1}}\right)$

Tags: convergence-divergence

I know this series is converges by limit test, but i can't find a way to calculate its sum.

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{4^{n-1}}{5^{n-1}}+\frac{4}{5^{n-1}}\right)$$
Thanks for helping,Here is the solution.

Solutions :
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{4^{n-1}}{5^{n-1}}+\frac{4}{5^{n-1}}\right)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac45\right)^{n-1}+4\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac15\right)^{n-1}$$
First thing to do is taking out the constant terms, which is $$\left(\frac45\right)^{-1},\left(\frac15\right)^{-1}$$
We can see there are two geometric series:
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac45\right)^{n}=\frac{\frac45}{1-\frac45}=4$$
Another one is: $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac15\right)^{n}=\frac{\frac45}{1-\frac45}=\frac14$$

So,we have 
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac45\right)^{n-1}+4\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac15\right)^{n-1}=\frac{5}{4}\cdot4+4\cdot5\cdot\frac14$$

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac45\right)^{n-1}+4\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac15\right)^{n-1}=10$$

Comment: You should add some detail more about the context for your answer and what you have tried with that.

Comment: Very nice work! Now as you can see you question has been reopened after your improvements. Please for the next time follow the indications given here on [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Bye

Answer (score 1):

We can use that

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{4^{n-1}}{5^{n-1}}+\frac{4}{5^{n-1}}\right)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac45\right)^{n-1}+4\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac15\right)^{n-1}$$

Can you conclude using geometric series?

Comment: I see it now...two geometric series,so it becomes (5/4)*((4/5)/(1-(4/5)))+4*((1/5)/(1-(1/5)))=10.Am i right? Thanks

Comment: Yes exactly! Well done. It would be nice if you can add your solution editing your question. Bye

Comment: I will add it in my question.Thanks for your help :P

Comment: @PatricEz You are welcome! Bye